# Am I right in calculating confidence interval?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, z-test

Task: In voting 20% of people among 1000 voted "yes", how many "yes" voted will be among 1 million responders?
My approach:
Ground truth is distributed normally with

```
mean = 0.2
n = 1000
std = sqrt(0.2*0.8)/sqrt(1000) ~ 0.12 
-> 95% CI will be:
[0.2-1.96*0.12; 0.2+1.96*0.12] = [0.175; 0.225] , where 1.96 is Z-value
```

->
with 95% confidence we can say that among 1 million responders "yes" will say between 1750000 and 225000 responders.

Is my approach right or I missed something?

Comment: How did you find $0.2,0.8$ and what is sort (is it $\sqrt{}$)? Can you try to explain in multiple lines with clear spaces?

Comment: @gunes , oops, my fail. 20% is initial proportion, not 30%. Yes, sort means square root, edited in body. sqrt(0.2*0.8) = sqrt(p*(1-p)), std for proportions

Comment: Then your mean is not 0.3. Reiterating, please use clear spaces between your formulas.

Comment: reformatted, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct, except the typos in-between (e.g. not `0.12`, it is approx. `0.012`). What you do is CI for population proportion. Using $\hat{p}=0.2$ and the confidence interval is defined as 
$$\hat{p}\pm z_{\alpha}\sqrt\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}\rightarrow0.2\pm1.96\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{0.2\times0.8}{1000}}}_{\approx0.0126}\rightarrow[0.175,0.225]$$
If you multiply these with `1M`, we get $[175K,225K]$ (you also have a typo here: `1750000`)

Comment: Viewing this as a _prediction_ interval, I'm having trouble seeing how the error from the second survey of a million subjects is accounted for. Not saying your answer is wrong, just wondering. Tried what I thought might be a better approach, but got substantially this same numerical end result.

Comment: @BruceET Your conceptual approach is the right one, but a million people is so large that constructing a confidence interval for the sum is an excellent approximation to the prediction interval for the sum.  There is a profound error lurking beneath all these calculations, though: a set of "voters" rarely acts like a random sample.  Without any additional information, the right answer in practice is going to be the interval $[200, 999200].$